# compare variables in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have three variables namely redcount, greencount and bluecount (already calculated in same pig program)
I want to compare their value and display largest of three with name.

existing code as below

```
countryflags = LOAD '/home/rahul/countryprojectdata/Country.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (country:chararray,landmass:int,zone:int,area_1ksqmtr:int,popoulation_million:int,language:int,religion:int,n_vbars:int,n_stripes:int,n_colors:int,redcolour:int,greencolour:int,bluecolour:int,goldcolour:int,whitecolour:int,blackcolour:int,orangecolour:int,mainhue:chararray,n_circles:int,n_upcrosses:int,n_digonalcrosses:int,n_quarteredsections:int,n_sunstars:int,crescent:int,triangle:int,icon:int,animate:int,text:int,topleftcolour:chararray,bottomrightcolour:chararray);

grpred = GROUP countryflags BY redcolour;
redcount = FOREACH grpred GENERATE SUM(countryflags.redcolour);

grpgreen = GROUP countryflags BY greencolour;
greencount = FOREACH grpgreen GENERATE SUM(countryflags.greencolour);

grpblue = GROUP countryflags BY bluecolour;
bluecount = FOREACH grpblue GENERATE SUM(countryflags.bluecolour);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION the three relations, sort and get the top record.Assuming you just want the name of the color and the largest count.

```
grpred = GROUP countryflags BY redcolour;
redcount = FOREACH grpred GENERATE 'red' as name,SUM(countryflags.redcolour) as red_sum;

grpgreen = GROUP countryflags BY greencolour;
greencount = FOREACH grpgreen GENERATE 'green' as name,SUM(countryflags.greencolour) green_sum;

grpblue = GROUP countryflags BY bluecolour;
bluecount = FOREACH grpblue GENERATE 'blue' as name,SUM(countryflags.bluecolour) as blue_sum;

A = UNION redcount,greencount,bluecount;
B = ORDER BY $1 DESC; -- Note: $1 because,we are creating a new column name else $0;
C = LIMIT B 1;
DUMP C;
```